# Erro ao converter um Enum

Tags: c#, mvc, enums

Boa noite pessoal, sou novo em C# e gostaria se possível de uma ajuda, criei um Enum com códigos de cliente e estou tentando passar o valor dele passando por uma validação e estou recebendo erro de conversão de string para int,

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cliente' to data type int."

Creio que meu Enum já seja int e não sei o porque recebo o erro, segue abaixo:

Meu enum:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Clientes ClienteId { get; set; }
    
}

public enum Clientes : int
{
    Cliente = 1,
    Cliente2 = 2
}
```

na Index pego ele assim:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Cliente,"--Escolha o cliente--")
```

A query :

```
public DataTable ConsultarPedido(string pedidoid,Clientes cliente)
{
    try
    {
        var consultar = $@"SELECT p.pedidoid, p.clienteid, p.statuspedido FROM dbo.Pedido p JOIN dbo.ItemPedido ip ON p.PedidoId = ip.PedidoId WHERE  p.PedidoId ='{pedidoid}' AND p.ClienteId='{cliente}'";

        return new AcessoBanco().RunQuery(consultar).Tables[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente, **seu valor enumerado está recebendo uma conversão implícita para `string`**, dado que está em uma [interpolação de string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) e sua coluna aceita apenas valores `int`.

Isso significa que no seu valor `cliente` o método `ToString()` está sendo chamado em tempo de execução para possibilitar a formatação da `string` final (que, no seu caso, é a query). Tente fazer a conversão dele para `int` ao passar o valor, seja convertendo com a [classe Convert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=net-5.0) ou por [*casting*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions):

`Convert.ToInt32(cliente)` ou `(int)cliente`.

O resultado final deveria refletir em `"1"`, por exemplo e não `"Cliente"` como ocorre na conversão de `enum` para `string`.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Ruan muito obrigado pela ajuda, na minha controller eu fiz isso:public ActionResult Index(Pedido itens)
        {            
            {                
                var pedido = new Pedido();
                                
                ViewData["Pedidoid"] = pedido.Pedidoid;
                ViewData["Cliente"] = (int)pedido.Cliente;  Não sei onde tenho que fazer a conversão.

Comment: Tente fazer a conversão **durante a montagem da sua query (na interpolação `{cliente}`)**. A interpolação que mencionei vai chamar o método `ToString()` no que estiver disponível, visando formatar a `string` corretamente. O erro que está recebendo chama sua `string` de `varchar`, então muito provavelmente está vindo da API de conexão com seu banco de dados, ou seja, durante a execução da query convertida.

Comment: Ok entendi, muito obrigado Ruan vou ajustar.